# Django int comparison not working

Tags: python, django, if-statement, int

This is a really odd question, but I don't understand why this is happening:

I've written this code:

```
stusr = int(su.total)
if not stusr == 0:
```

But, even I do know for fact that stusr.total will never be 0 (It always gets initialized),  it never executes the if command. Even when I try to divide by su.total to calculate a percentage, I get errors saying I cannot divide by 0.

When I show `stusr` in screen I get non-zero values, so I'm sure I initialize it correctly.

Here's my model

```
class StatsUser(models.Model):
  correct = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  incorrect = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  total = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  ...
```

Hope you can help me understand this.

Comment: Can you show us what `su` is?

Comment: su = StatsUser.objects.get(user=u)

Comment: You are doing `objects.get`, it will expect to get only one object and will throw exceptions in case there are none or more objects. And even if you do `objects.filter()`, QuerySet objects don't have any attribute `total`. So, I'm sure this is not the value of `su`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's a strange idiom, it should work. Try the following (using the correct syntax):

```
stusr = int(su.total)
if stusr:             # (all non-zero integer values are true)
    print("Yay, stusr is nonzero!")
else:
    print("Wha? But su.total is {}!".format(repr(su.total)))
```

Comment: I get "Wha? But su.total is 167"

Comment: ['Wha? But su.total is 0!']

Comment: 'Yay, stusr is nonzero!'

Comment: Ok, I know why this is happening: I'm trying to calculate percentages using int instead of float ¬¬

Answer (score 1):

Can't you do a `print su.total` before casting to an int? To see what it's value is before casting.
Furthermore, the total field is an IntegerField, these fields don't have to cast to an int.